# Система счисления

Tags: системы-счисления

Задача:чему равна сумма чисел 266(8) и 588(16)?Ответ представить в двоичной системе счисления.(8) и (16)-основания.Объясните пожалуйста алгоритм!Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

перевести два числа в удобную систему счисления (например, в десятичную), выполнить нужные операции и перевести в двоичную.

Более правильный алгоритм. Так как результат нужен в двоичной системе, то можно два числа перевести сразу в двоичную. А так как они в [8](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) и [16-чной](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) системе, то перевод очень простой. Это буквально подмена цифр на числа.

```
266 => 010 110 110 
588 => 0101 1000 1000
```

Сложить их очень просто.

```
   010110110 
010110001000
------------
*1**00***110
```

Я специально заменил некоторые цифры звездочками, что бы дать Вам возможность немножко поработать самостоятельно.